# change each keys of a dictionary based on length of each values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{ 1:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] , 2:['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'] , 3:['E', 'AD', 'BC'] , 4:['BC', 'EAD'] , 5:['BCEAD'] }
```

is there a way to set length of each value of dictionary as its key ?

I mean, I want to have this dictionary :

```
  { 5:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] , 4:['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'] , 3:['E', 'AD', 'BC'] , 2:['BC','EAD'] , 1:['BCEAD'] }
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What should happen if there are 2 or more lists of equal length?

Comment: What happens if one item has the same length - `1` has 5 items, `3` has 5 items?  Because dictionary does NOT allow duplicated keys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse all values of your original dictionary with `values()` and `list()` function:

```
d = { 1:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] , 2:['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'] , 3:['E', 'AD', 'BC'] , 4:['BC', 'EAD'] , 5:['BCEAD'] }

newD = {}

for i in list(d.values()):
    newD[len(i)] = i
print(newD)
```

**Output:** *Note that if you have several values of the same length, the dictionary will only have one key. You can't have more than 1 key being the same in a dictionary*

```
{5: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 4: ['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'], 3: ['E', 'AD', 'BC'], 2: ['BC', 'EAD'], 1: ['BCEAD']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict comprehension which is very pythonic:

```py
dict_ = { 1:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] , 2:['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'] , 3:['E', 'AD', 'BC'] , 4:['BC', 'EAD'] , 5:['BCEAD'] }
dict2 = {len(v) : v for k, v in dict_.items()}
>>> {5: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 4: ['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'], 3: ['E', 'AD', 'BC'], 2: ['BC', 'EAD'], 1: ['BCEAD']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
dict_old = {1: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 2: ['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'], 3: ['E', 'AD', 'BC'], 4: ['BC', 'EAD'], 5: ['BCEAD']}
dict_new = {}
for k, v in dict_old.items():
    dict_new[len(v)] = v
print(dict_new)
```

Comment: To improve this and future answers, please include the output of your solution along with your code, so others can immediately see the result. You can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it by `dict comprehension`:

```
>>> dict_ = { 1:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] , 2:['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'] , 3:['E', 'AD', 'BC'] , 4:['BC', 'EAD'] , 5:['BCEAD'] }
>>> dict2 = {len(v) : v for _, v in dict_.items()}
{5: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 4: ['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'], 3: ['E', 'AD', 'BC'], 2: ['BC', 'EAD'], 1: ['BCEAD']}
```

or you could do that with a `map` function:

```
>>> dict_ = {
1:['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] , 
2:['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'] , 
3:['E', 'AD', 'BC'] , 
4:['BC', 'EAD'] , 
5:['BCEAD'] }

>>> new_dict = dict(map(lambda x:(len(x[1]),x[1]),dict_))
>>> new_dict
{5: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 4: ['B', 'C', 'E', 'AD'],
 3: ['E', 'AD', 'BC'],
 2: ['BC', 'EAD'],
 1: ['BCEAD']}
```